# Keeping track of count in python data structure

Tags: python

I have a large (~50GB) dataset that contains data that looks like this:

```
Group: 1
Attribute 1: 'AAA'
Attribute 2: 3

Group: 1
Attribute 1: 'AAA'
Attribute 2: 3

Group: 1
Attribute 1: 'TTTT'
Attribute 2: 4

Group: 2
Attribute 1: 'GG'
Attribute 2: 2

Group: 2
Attribute 1: 'GG'
Attribute 2: 2
```

I would like to compile all of the data together in python but I'm not sure how to design the data structure.

My idea is to build a data structure that looks something like the following. In this example, the data is added, but if a row already exists with the same data in `Group`, `A1`, and `A2`, a `Count` column is just incremented instead of creating another row.

```
Group   A1      A2  Count
1       AAA     3   2
1       TTTT    4   1
2       GG      2   2
```

Comment: Could you expand your incoming dataset so that it would generate your expected output? It's not clear how the count of 10 is achieved.

Comment: Do you want to use Pandas?

Comment: `"large (~50GB) dataset that contains data that looks like..."`-  what is the dataset? is it a csv? database? dataframe? array? dictionary? json? text?

Comment: @alex I included all the data to hopefully help. I have already read everything in as variables so i'm not entirely sure the most helpful way to display; hopefully clear as is now.

Comment: @Corralien I don't need to use pandas, but fine with using it.

Comment: Are there always two attributes? Or are you aiming for something more generic?

Comment: @TheNightman, its still not clear what the data is. What is the input data type, is it a text file? What is the output data type, is it a `pandas.DataFrame`?

Comment: @AkshaySehgal the data is currently held in a number of text files that i'm already iterating through. So i have the data being already read into variables.

Comment: @TheNightman, is the variable that you are storing the text file a string? what is the `type(input_text)`?

Comment: What is the type of variables? a list of dict?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) and [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from the standard library collections module.

```
from collections import namedtuple, Counter

Foo = namedtuple('Foo', ['Group', 'A1', 'A2'])
Counter([
    Foo(1, 'AAA', 3),
    Foo(1, 'AAA', 3),
    Foo(1, 'TTTT', 4),
    Foo(2, 'GG', 2),
    Foo(2, 'GG', 2),
])
```

output:

```
Counter({Foo(Group=1, A1='AAA', A2=3): 2,
         Foo(Group=1, A1='TTTT', A2=4): 1,
         Foo(Group=2, A1='GG', A2=2): 2})
```

The reason for using namedtuple here is that Counter only works with hashable values.

You might need a lot of RAM if you build a list of your entire data set, to pass to Counte.

But if there's a small set of unique values in your input data, you could process the file one entry at a time with a generator function. This can be much more efficient in memory usage, since you don't need to load the full data set into memory at once.

```
def lazy_read(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            # assuming each line looks like this `1 AAA 3`
            group, A1, A2 = line.split()
            yield Foo(group, A1, A2)

Counter(lazy_read('foo.data'))
```

This `lazy_read` is just a minimal example. See the answer submitted by Alex for a more detailed generator function.

Comment: Thank you. Collections is one of those utility modules in the standard library that I find some use for in almost any project.

Answer (score 2):

You will most likely need to write some custom parsing code for this dataset, something like the following snippet. This will yield each group and all the attributes that follow it until the next group.

```py
def read_dataset(fh):
    # Iterate to get first record
    for line in fh:
        if line.lower().startswith("group"):
            name = line.strip()
            break
    # This list will hold the attribute lines
    lines = []

    # Now iterate to get attributes
    for line in fh:
        if line.lower().startswith("group"):
            # When in this block we have reached
            #  the next record

            # yield the previous record's name and
            #  attributes
            yield name, lines

            # Reset the attribute lines and save the
            #  name of the next record
            lines = []
            name = line.strip()

            # skip to next line
            continue
        if line.strip():
            lines.append(line.strip())
    yield name, lines
```

You can then iterate through the file relatively easily, processing each group into something like from [Håken's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69623084/3279716).

```py
with open("dataset.txt", "r") as file_handle:
    for group, attrs in read_dataset(file_handle):
        ...
        # Process group to get number
        # Process attrs 
        # Write directly to a CSV or compute counts now
```